# Spark-Scala RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD `RDD1` with the following Schema:

```
RDD[String, Array[String]]
```

(let's call it `RDD1`)

and I would like create a new RDD `RDD2` with each row as `RDD[String,String]` with the key and value belonging to `RDD1`.

For example:

```
RDD1 =Array(("Fruit",("Orange","Apple","Peach")),("Shape",("Square","Rectangle")),("Mathematician",("Aryabhatt"))))
```

I want the output to be as:

```
RDD2 = Array(("Fruit","Orange"),("Fruit","Apple"),("Fruit","Peach"),("Shape","Square"),("Shape","Rectangle"),("Mathematician","Aryabhatt"))
```

Can someone help me with this piece of code?

My Try:

```
val R1 = RDD1.map(line => (line._1,line._2.split((","))))
val R2 = R1.map(line => line._2.foreach(ph => ph.map(line._1)))
```

This gives me an error:

> error: value map is not a member of Char

I understand that it is because that map function is only applicable to the `RDDs` and not each `string/char`. Please help me with a way to use nested functions for this purpose in `Spark`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break down the problem.

1. `("Fruit",Array("Orange","Apple","Peach")` -> `Array(("Fruit", "Orange"), ("Fruit", "Apple"), ("Fruit", "Peach"))`

`def flattenLine(line: (String, Array[String])) = line._2.map(x => (line._1, x)`

2. Apply that function to your rdd:

`rdd1.flatMap(flattenLine)`